# Problem of push from my app because of SPLIT_BUNDLE 59 google play console

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, google-play-console

I have a problem with my react native(expo) application on the google store, every time I try to push it I get this message from google:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XZLu.png)

I tried everything, I filled in the requested forms on security and data types, and I also added in the config of my application that I read the contact information and that I also open the camera like this:

```
  "permissions": [
        "READ_CONTACTS",
        "CAMERA"
      ],
```

I don't know what else to do, if someone has an idea, I don't understand what they want from me, plus I can't contact them...

Answer (score 0):

This means your app is creating a new unique id using UUID for advertising or analytics.
Just goto PlayConsole -> Select App -> App Content -> Data Safety Option -> Select unique ID's and write the reason to use this.
Submit it for review and it might take 1-2 days to get reviewed and it will get resolved.
Here is the complete information for the Data Safety forum ->

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10787469?hl=en